# Fragment layout exits my app when phone screen turns off or sleeps

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need help, am using a fragment to hold a list of items, but when the fragment layout is the active layout on the screen, when the phone screen light turns off or sleeps, it exits the application. Please, what could be the cause?

This is my code below:

Fragment Layout for the list items

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".BookChapters">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:clipChildren="false">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header_book_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:src="@drawable/default_book"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/chapterList_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/chapters_recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Fragment BookChapters.java class

```
public class BookChapters extends Fragment implements ChapterListAdapter.ListItemClickListener, Player.EventListener{
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnChapterSelectedListener mListener;

ImageView bookImage;
ArrayList<Chapter> chapters;
RecyclerView chaptersRecycler;
ChapterListAdapter adapter;

Toolbar mToolbar;

private MediaSource mediaSource;
private SimpleExoPlayer player;
static MediaSessionCompat mMediaSession;
PlaybackStateCompat.Builder playbackState;
PlaybackStateCompat.Builder mStateBuilder;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

private boolean playWhenReady = true;
private int currentWindow = 0;
private long playbackPosition = 0;
private int currentPosition = 0;

private int MEDIA_PLAYING_STATE = 0;

private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "media_playback_channel";
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 100;

ChaptersPagerAdapter chaptersPagerAdapter;
int activePosition = 0;

PlayerNotificationManager playerNotificationManager;

public BookChapters() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment BookChapters.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static BookChapters newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    BookChapters fragment = new BookChapters();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_book_chapters, container, false);

    mMediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(getActivity(), "TAG");
    mMediaSession.setFlags(MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS |
            MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
    mMediaSession.setMediaButtonReceiver(null);

    mStateBuilder = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder();
    playbackState = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder().setActions(PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY |
    PlaybackState.ACTION_PAUSE | PlaybackState.ACTION_FAST_FORWARD |
    PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE | PlaybackState.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT |
    PlaybackState.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS | PlaybackState.ACTION_REWIND);

    mMediaSession.setPlaybackState(playbackState.build());
    mMediaSession.setCallback(new mySessionCallback());
    mMediaSession.setActive(true);

    playerNotificationManager = new PlayerNotificationManager(
        getActivity(),
        CHANNEL_ID,
        NOTIFICATION_ID, new DescriptionAdapter());

    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getActivity().getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
            "MyApp::MyWakelockTag");
    wakeLock.acquire();

    // omit fast forward action by setting the increment to zero
    playerNotificationManager.setFastForwardIncrementMs(0);
    // omit rewind action by setting the increment to zero
    playerNotificationManager.setRewindIncrementMs(0);
    // omit the stop action
    playerNotificationManager.setStopAction(null);
    playerNotificationManager.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.talking_bookz);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.chapterList_toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    String bookTitle = this.getArguments().getString("book_title");

    ActionBar supportActionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    if (supportActionBar != null){
        supportActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp);
        supportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        supportActionBar.setTitle(bookTitle);
    }

    String book_image = this.getArguments().getString("book_design");
    bookImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.header_book_image);
    volleyImageLoader(book_image);

    chaptersRecycler = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.chapters_recycler);
    chaptersRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

    chapters = (ArrayList<Chapter>) this.getArguments().getSerializable("chapters");

    adapter = new ChapterListAdapter(getContext(), chapters, this);
    chaptersRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);


    chaptersPagerAdapter = new ChaptersPagerAdapter(getContext(), chapters);
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).chaptersRecycler.setAdapter(chaptersPagerAdapter);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (player.getPlaybackState() == ExoPlayer.STATE_READY) {
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void setOnBookChapterSelected(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onChapterSelected(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(int position) {
    Chapter chapter = chapters.get(position);
    String url = chapter.getChapterAudioUrl();
    String bookTitle = chapter.getBookTitle();
    String bookAuthor = chapter.getBookAuthor();
    String chapterTitle = chapter.getChapterTitle();
    String bookImage = chapter.getBookImage();

    currentPosition = position;
    chaptersRecycler.scrollToPosition(currentPosition);
    playAudio(bookImage, url, bookTitle, bookAuthor, chapterTitle);
}


/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnChapterSelectedListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onChapterSelected(Uri uri);
}

public void volleyImageLoader(String url){
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppSingleton.getInstance(getContext()).getImageLoader();

    imageLoader.get(url, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean arg1) {
            if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                bookImage.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());

            }
        }
    });
}

private void playAudio(String bookImage, String media, String bookTitle, String authur, String chapterTitle) {

    if (player != null) {
        player.stop(true);
        player.release();
        player = null;
    }

    initializePlayer(media);

    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).miniBookTitle.setText(bookTitle);
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).miniBookAuthor.setText(authur);

    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).txtMediaBookTitle.setText(bookTitle);
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).txtMediaBookAuthor.setText(authur);
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).txtMediaBookChapter.setText(chapterTitle);

    MEDIA_PLAYING_STATE = 1;
    volleyImageLoader(bookImage, ((MainActivity) getActivity()).miniBookImage);

}

private void initializePlayer(String url) {
    if (player == null) {
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(getContext(),
                new DefaultTrackSelector(), new DefaultLoadControl());
        player.addListener(this);
        playerNotificationManager.setPlayer(player);
        playerNotificationManager.setMediaSessionToken(mMediaSession.getSessionToken());

        player.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady);
        player.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition);

        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).playerControlView.setPlayer(player);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).miniPlayerControlView.setPlayer(player);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri);
        player.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);
    }
}

private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {
    return new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(
            new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer-codelab")).
            createMediaSource(uri);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
    if((playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_READY) && playWhenReady){
        mStateBuilder.setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING,
                player.getCurrentPosition(), 1f);
        Log.d("onPlayerStateChanged:", "PLAYING");
    } else if((playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_READY)){
        mStateBuilder.setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED,
                player.getCurrentPosition(), 1f);
        Log.d("onPlayerStateChanged:", "PAUSED");
    }
    mMediaSession.setPlaybackState(mStateBuilder.build());
}

private class DescriptionAdapter implements
        PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter {

    @Override
    public String getCurrentContentTitle(Player player) {
        Chapter chapter = chapters.get(currentPosition);
        return  chapter.getBookTitle();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getCurrentContentText(Player player) {
        Chapter chapter = chapters.get(currentPosition);
        return chapter.getChapterNumber() + ": " + chapter.getChapterTitle();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Bitmap getCurrentLargeIcon(Player player,
                                      PlayerNotificationManager.BitmapCallback callback) {
        int window = player.getCurrentWindowIndex();
        Bitmap largeIcon = null;
        return largeIcon;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public PendingIntent createCurrentContentIntent(Player player) {
        int window = player.getCurrentWindowIndex();
        return null;//createPendingIntent(window);
    }
}

private void releasePlayer(){
    playerNotificationManager.setPlayer(null);
    player.stop();
    player.release();
    player = null;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

public void volleyImageLoader(String url, final ImageView imageView){
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppSingleton.getInstance(getContext()).getImageLoader();

    imageLoader.get(url, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("debugger", "Image Load Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean arg1) {
            if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
            }
        }
    });
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private class mySessionCallback extends MediaSessionCompat.Callback {
    @Override
    public void onPlay() {
        super.onPlay();
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipToPrevious() {
        super.onSkipToPrevious();
        activePosition -= 1;
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).layoutManager.setInitialPrefetchItemCount(activePosition);
        Log.d("debuugger", "Media Position: " + player.getCurrentPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipToNext() {
        super.onSkipToNext();
        activePosition += 1;
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).layoutManager.setInitialPrefetchItemCount(activePosition);
        Log.d("debuugger", "Media Position: " + player.getCurrentPosition());
    }
}
```

}

Then the code I used in Launching the BookChapters Fragment is below

```
MainActivity myActivity = (MainActivity) context;
            BookChapters myBookChaptersFragment = new BookChapters();
            myBookChaptersFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            myActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                    replace(R.id.book_chapters_fragment_container, myBookChaptersFragment, "book_chapters")
                    .addToBackStack("book_chapters")
                    .commit();
```